# OpenCL constructor syntax and updating variable

Tags: opencl

I'm getting some seemingly odd results when I try to update a `float3` variable in an OpenCL kernel. Boiling it down:

```
float3 vel = float3( 0 );   // a
vel = float3( 0, 1, 0 );    // b
vel = (float3)( 0, 2, 0 );  // c
```

If I print `vel` after each call with:

```
if( get_global_id( 0 ) == 0 )
    printf( "[%d]: vel: ( %f, %f, %f )\n", index, vel.x, vel.y, vel.z );
```

Then I see that a) correctly initializes `vel`, however b) doesn't do anything. c) works. Does anyone know why I can't update the variable with a new `float3` object as I'm doing in b? This is how I'm used to doing it in C++ and glsl. Or possibly a driver bug?

Using OpenCL 1.2 on macbook pro running OS X 10.11.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `c)` is a correct way of initialising/using vector types. `a)` and `b)` is possibly a bug in Mac implementation (on 2 GPUs and 1CPU I tried that didn't compile).

Few ways of initialising vector type:

```
float3 vel = (float3)( 1,1,1 );
float3 vel2 = (float3) 1;  // it will be ( 1,1,1 )
float3 vel3 = 1;  // it will be ( 1,1,1 )
```

More about usage of vector types: [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.x-latest.pdf#page=131)

Answer (score 2):

In C, the comma operator has very specific semantics, as described in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) (or more briefly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558/3100482)):

> `(a, b, c)` is a sequence of expressions, separated by commas, which evaluates to the last expression `c`

For your second approach (`b`), this means that your expression will boil down to `float(0)`, which gives you the same result as in the first approach (`a`).

Your third approach (`c`) is making use of specific syntax introduced by OpenCL C which allows for initialising individual elements of a vector, and so doesn't fall into this trap.

Comment: If I can add to the question: What does `float3( 0, 1, 0 )` boil down to? float3 is not a class, has no constructor, and this is not C++... Also case a) ? how does that even work?

Comment: @DarkZeros This is certainly not standard OpenCL C syntax, so likely won't work everywhere (or even anywhere else other than Apple).

Comment: Sadistic compiler authors don't even warn on the C++ style vector constructor style, silently producing a vector with all components set to the last one specified. ಠ_ಠ